# Show that the function$f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{xyz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Show that the function
$f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{xyz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, (x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$
$f(x,y,z)=0, (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$

Is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$

I use this formula to show that the function is differentiable
$\exists\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_1(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta x , \varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_2(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta y ,\varepsilon_3(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta z$ such that
$\Delta u = f(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z) - f(0,0,0) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0,0)\Delta x + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0)\Delta y + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0)\Delta z + \varepsilon_1(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta x + \varepsilon_2(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta y + \varepsilon_3(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta z$
where $\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\to(0,0,0)}\varepsilon_1(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta x=0,
 \lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\to(0,0,0)}\varepsilon_2(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta y = 0,
\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\to(0,0,0)}\varepsilon_3(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta z =0$

I substitute what I calculated, that
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0,0)\Delta x  = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0)\Delta y = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0)\Delta z = 0$

So $\Delta u$ now is

$\dfrac{\Delta x \Delta y (\Delta z)^2}{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}= \varepsilon_1(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta x + \varepsilon_2(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta y + \varepsilon_3(\Delta x,\Delta y, \Delta z)\Delta z$

I stuck there and not sure that I can't prove that the function is differentiable. I think the function is not differentiable.

Comment: In last equation, in denominator - you have multiplication or sum?

Comment: Oh I mean sum. Thanks for correction

Comment: At $(0,0,0)$ I think you want $f=0$ rather than $(0,0,0),$ since at non-origin points output is a singe real number not  triple.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice that. Thank You.

Comment: yes, $\dfrac{z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $is bounded  near the origin, $\dfrac{yz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},$  is continuous, $\dfrac{xyz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},$  is differentiable